# How can I baby-proof my 75" TV?

Tags: infant, safety, television

I have a 10 month old son. He's able to stand on his own and crawl, and his favorite place to be is at the TV stand. I have a 75" TV in a place he can unfortunately reach. There is no possible way for us to mount it to the wall or move it, as it's in the only place it will fit.

My concern is that he likes to go up and hit it with his hands or with a toy; seeing how expensive this TV was, I'm terrified he's going to break it. What are any ways I can prevent that?

Comment: Almost all TV these days comes with safety straps so you can tie to the wall or another stable object behind it.

Comment: Defo strap it, it will prevent the TV to tilt and fall but it won't shield it from flying objects like it happened to ours <crack>. You could still get a screen protector fitted until your son makes sense of "no" but that defeats the purpose of having a nice TV as it will look ugly and alter the picture quality

Comment: By TV-proofing your 10-mo-old baby.

Comment: I can't answer without 10 rep. Large baby pen on amazon. As they get older everything in the house "moves up" to keep out of hands reach... but right around the time they're crawling to learning to walk well, its impossible to keep them out of everything all the time and a large 6x7 foot pen has helped. Toys go in the pen, and siblings and parents too.

And yes please make sure the TV wont topple now, before you forget.

Answer (score 47):

I'd be more concerned with a 75" TV falling on my infant and hurting him!  A 75" television can weigh up to 100 pounds - that's a lot of weight to be falling on a 24 pound infant.

There are a few things you can do to protect the television *and* the infant. One is to use safety straps - these don't mount the television to the wall, but they do attach to either the wall or the stand, and prevent it from tipping forward.

Another is to gate around the television - the whole way around.  You don't say how it's placed in your house, but however that is, you can use gates - just perhaps a lot of them.

Another option might be to have a larger TV stand.  Babies want to touch and hold onto things while they're learning to walk, and so a larger table/stand that gives a good amount of space before the baby gets to the television will help a lot here as well.

Mainly, though, a child that age should not be unsupervised for *any* period of time - so the best protector for your television is yourself.  Kindly teach your child not to throw things at the television, and redirect your child in more safe directions, as necessary.  And, perhaps, reduce your time in front of the television - the things you're interested in, your child will be interested in.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142553/discussion-on-answer-by-joe-how-can-i-baby-proof-my-75-tv); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 7):

I will not address how to protect the TV from toppling over.  But to protect the TV from impact from toys (for example), screen protectors are sold which you can affix to the front of the TV.  These are giant-sized versions of the screen protectors people put on their mobile phones.  They are expensive; a quick search shows several in the $300-$400 USD price range.  Whether that is worth the cost will depend will depend upon the price of your TV and how likely you believe it is to be damaged.

Comment: I'd not heard of those - I wonder if their primary market is for environments with child-like adults (e.g. pubs)?  Sounds like a good idea, anyway: +1

Comment: A sheet of polycarbonate will cost less than 100 USD and can be attached with tape - it will not be as neat looking though, and will increase reflections.

Answer (score 5):

Swap the TV out for a projector with a roll-up screen mounted to your ceiling.

That's totally kids proof, not too expensive and gives you a larger screen diameter.

Also, you can now use the wall behind the projector screen.

Comment: ... and you can only watch it at night, unless you get good blackout curtains for the windows.  Not that I'm encouraging watching TV all day, but I wouldn't want to rule out the possibility of *ever* watching in the daytime...

Comment: I am using a projector for 7 years now. Daytime watching has never been an issue. No blackout curtains needed, just a projector with a half-decent light output. Many people only have experiences with bad/old projectors. If you get something with at least 3500 lumens, daytime viewing is no issue at all. Also, you need a half-decent projector screen. Walls reflect all light, decent projector screens reflect light from the projector more than ambient light. But yeah, if you get a €100 projector with 500 lumens and project to a wall, you won't be happy. But you also bought the wrong thing.

Comment: It's the same projector for all that time, btw. I had to replace the bulb once, which cost me around €20. Power consumption is 280W in non-eco-mode, which is a bit, but not more than a TV of similar size.

Answer (score 3):

TV stands don't have to be mounted to the wall these days. I have a 65" TV and the most surprising thing is how light it is (compared to the older tube TVs, which weighed a ton). Thus, you can have a TV mounted to a stand (with or without furniture).

[image: Furniture with TV stand]

Another option is to get a higher piece of furniture. I built a TV stand a few years ago that's about 3ft(1M) tall. Makes the TV harder to reach for your child.

Answer (score 0):

A TV cabinet with a roll up door. And put some kind of childproof latch/lock on the door.

There don't seem to be a lot of pre-built options but you can DIY this or get one made custom. Since this is kind of a niche item, I would personally recommend a normal base with a detachable hutch that has the actual doors. Then you can disassemble it to move it or if you decide you no longer need the doors.

Don't forget to 1) secure the hutch against falling over by securing it to the wall, and 2) have an access hole in the back of the hutch to still secure the TV directly to the wall (to prevent falling over).

Comment: Roll up door for a 75" TV is more akin to a garage door, right? ;)

Comment: Speaking from experience, most TVs these days are far too large to fit **inside** a cabinet. A 75" TV would need  roughly 70" of width (about 6ft/2m) for the TV to clear the insides *and* leave the buttons on the side or back accessible. That's a BIG cabinet. The ones I've seen all stop around the 60" TV mark, and I've not seen any with doors. A 3ft/1m door would be fairly heavy and require a substantial hinge. Not impossible to make, but harder to do with the MDF most cabinets are made from.